# jQuery Next/Prev Smooth Scrolling menu

Tags: jquery, wordpress, scroll

I have found the perfect example of jQuery Next/Prev Vertical Smooth Scrolling [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780047/jquery-next-prev-smooth-scrolling-and-wordpress) and its working for me (I havesite on WordPress). [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HRewD/17/) But I am not much familiar with JS and need help with menu items. In this code I have only two items: next and previous. How I can add another extra items to my menu items in this JQ code. And can i fix my menu in one place like on enloop.com/features 
[Working example](http://bpe24.ru/?page_id=647)

```
<div id="home-block">
    <div class="current">Content Goes here</div>
    <div>A box of content</div>
    <div>Content</div>
    <div>More content...</div>
</div>

<div id="nav-right">
    <a href="#" id="prev">Previous</a>
    <a href="#" id="next">Next</a>
</div>

#home-block div{
width: 300px;
height: 400px;
border: 1px solid #000;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #888;
margin: 10px 10px 10px 15px;
}

.post-contain{
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 450px;
border: 1px solid #000;
}

#nav-right{
    position: fixed;
    right: 15px;
    top: 35%;
}

.current {
    color: red;
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var scrollTo = function(element) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: element.offset().top
        }, 250);
    }
    $('#next').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $current = $('#home-block > .current');
        if ($current.index() != $('#home-block > div').length - 1) {
            $current.removeClass('current').next().addClass('current');
            scrollTo($current.next());
        }
    });
    $('#prev').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $current = $('#home-block > .current');
        if (!$current.index() == 0) {
           $current.removeClass('current').prev().addClass('current');
            scrollTo($current.prev());
        }
    });
})();
```

Your help will be greatly appriciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `#next` and `#prev` links call `scrollTo(element)`. You can still utilize that function, you only need to change how you identify the element to scroll to, based on what your new menu will look like.

- [Demo using `id` and `href`](http://jsfiddle.net/W4AWs/)
- [Demo using element index](http://jsfiddle.net/FWXc5/)

You'll note that I moved the setter of the `current` class to the `scrollTo` function. You can of course keep that in the menu listeners if you wish...

Comment: David, thank you very much! I have one question. On your example i see smooth scrolling. But on my page i couldnt achieve this. http://jsfiddle.net/Jjssd/ Could you tell what mistake i made. 
In my example blocks jumping 
I put JQ code in the same page with html code in WordPress. Whhat changes i should make to achive the smooth scroll effect like in your jsfiddle.
[Working example][1] 


  [1]: http://bpe24.ru/?page_id=647

Comment: You did not have jQuery included in the document (left menu). [same code, fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/jh6Jw/). Since you didn't have jQuery, the browser simply followed the link to `#plan` (for instance), and if you link to an ID, you scroll to that item. So the solution would work even for non-javascript enabled browsers (albeit without the smooth scrolling).

Comment: I understand. I don't know JQ, Can you give me advice and example of code how i can put JQ in my code for to make scroll move smooth.

Comment: The code in your fiddle works, you only need to make sure that the jQuery library is loaded in the document.

Comment: I am sorry for stuped question, but how i can check this. Previuos codewas working. I put JQ on the page, not ibn the header or function. How i can check this.

Comment: In your first fiddle you had selected "jQuery 1.6.4" in the left-hand menu. In the second fiddle you posted, you've left it at "No library (pure JS)". This is the only reason the second fiddle isn't working. Select a framework (jQuery) and it'll work.

Comment: I am selected and its not working( On me site http://bpe24.ru/?page_id=647#service its not working too. What can i do? I have JQ library in my themes and i feel that i need to change something in JQ code but i don't know where.  Sorry that i didnt get your advice. Can you put all code with all changes?

Comment: In your non-working fiddle, [Jjssd](http://jsfiddle.net/Jjssd/), the only difference from my working fiddle, [jh6Jw](http://jsfiddle.net/jh6Jw/), is that a framework has been selected. You need to rerun the fiddle after you've selected a framework. In your live site, you get a javscript error because there's a `</p><p>` in the middle of your javascript code, that doesn't belong there.

Comment: David, thank you very much, its working! the only problem is that the menu fall down on footer and (the second problem) when i select the item the block starts not from the <h1> but from the text in the block. I cant see the text in <h1>